# ExecutionEngineException - Error at iOS Runtime with parse.com SDK

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, push-notification, il2cpp

We're creating a game for iOS and android using Unity3d (version 5.0.1p1), and since we are using Parse.com data services we naturally went with it to implement the remote push notifications.

The problem is that after building the game and running it on a test device (iPhone 4s iOS8.1.2) we get at game start an execution engine exception that we cant figure out. Here is the exception :

```
ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to call method

'System.Reflection.MonoProperty::StaticGetterAdapterFrame' for which no ahead of time (AOT) code was

generated.

at System.Reflection.EventInfo+AddEventAdapter.Invoke (System.Object
_this, System.Delegate dele)

[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at System.Reflection.MonoProperty+GetterAdapter.Invoke (System.Object
_this) [0x00000] in <filename

unknown>:0

at AOGenerator.BlurBuffer () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) [0x00000] in

<filename unknown>:0

at Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.BsonRegex.get_Type () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at Parse.ParseInstallation.get_Badge () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at Parse.ParseInstallation.SetPlatformAutomaticValue () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at Parse.ParseInstallation.SetAutomaticValues () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at Parse.ParseInstallation.SaveAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.Task toAwait, CancellationToken

cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at Parse.PlatformHooks+<>c__DisplayClass38.<RequestAsync>b__33 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 _)

[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at Parse.ParseObject+<>c__DisplayClass18.<SaveAsync>b__17 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task toAwait)

[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at FlurryAnalyticsIOS.SetSessionTimeout (Int32 seconds) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at

System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int64,System.Boolean].Do_ICollectionCopyTo[KeyValuePair`2]

(System.Array array, Int32 index, System.Collections.Generic.Transform`1 transform) [0x00000] in <filename

unknown>:0

at Parse.Internal.TaskQueue.Enqueue[Task] (System.Func`2 taskStart, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at Parse.ParseObject.SaveAsync (CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at Parse.ParseObject.SaveAsync () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at Parse.ParseInitializeBehaviour.<Awake>b__0 (System.Byte[] deviceToken) [0x00000] in <filename

unknown>:0

at FlurryAnalyticsIOS.SetSessionTimeout (Int32 seconds) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.BsonRegex.get_Type () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at Parse.PlatformHooks+<>c__DisplayClass24.<RegisterDeviceTokenRequest>b__22 () [0x00000] in

<filename unknown>:0

at System.Action.Invoke () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.BsonRegex.get_Type () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at Parse.PlatformHooks+<RunDispatcher>d__44.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

at System.Nullable`1[System.DateTimeOffset].ToString () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

System.Nullable`1:ToString()

UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_LogException(Exception, Object)

UnityEngine.Debug:LogException(Exception)

Parse.<RunDispatcher>d__44:MoveNext()

System.Nullable`1:ToString()
```

The problem just appeared with the new Unity Parse SDK 1.5 (which contains the PNS feature). What we know is that running an empty project with just the parse sdk goes fine and the notifications work just fine, but in our actual project, because of the exception, devices dont register for the notifications in parse, so we are assuming there is a kind of a conflict between parse and one of the other tools we are using.

FYI : We are building the game using IL2CPP for a universal architecture (we re also building with .Net 2.0 subset, but I dont think that this has something to do with the problem).

Thank you for your time and for your answers.

UPDATE ::

We tried to build using Mono(2.x) this time and we have pretty much the same exception that turned into this :

> ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method
>
> 'System.Reflection.MonoProperty:StaticGetterAdapterFrame
>
> (System.Reflection.MonoProperty/StaticGetter`1,object)' while
>   running with ­­aot­only.
>
> at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj,
>   System.Object[] index)
>
> [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Parse.ParseInstallation.get_Badge () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Parse.ParseInstallation.SetPlatformAutomaticValue () [0x00000] in
>
> unknown>:0
>
> at Parse.ParseInstallation.SetAutomaticValues () [0x00000] in
>   :0
>
> at Parse.ParseInstallation.SaveAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.Task
>   toAwait,
>
> CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Parse.ParseObject+<>c__DisplayClass18.b__17
>
> (System.Threading.Tasks.Task toAwait) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Parse.Internal.TaskQueue.Enqueue[Task] (System.Func`2 taskStart,
>   CancellationToken
>
> cancellationToken) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Parse.ParseObject.SaveAsync (CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   [0x00000] in
>
> :0
>
> at Parse.ParseObject.SaveAsync () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Parse.ParseInitializeBehaviour.b__0 (System.Byte[]
>   deviceToken) [0x00000] in
>
> :0
>
> at
>   Parse.PlatformHooks+<>c__DisplayClass24.b__22
>   ()
>
> [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Parse.PlatformHooks+d__44.MoveNext () [0x00000] in
>
> unknown>:0
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_LogException(Exception, Object)
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogException(Exception)
>
> Parse.d__44:MoveNext()

Hopes it bring you guys more details about the problem.

Update 2 ::

We know exactly what causes the exception to happen and unfortunately we have no control over it, its when we register for notification, we do it this way :

```
using NotificationServices = UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices;
using NotificationType = UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationType;

        /*
         .
         .
         .
         */

        void ACalledFunction ()
        {
            // Ask for permission for push notifications (Can Receive deviceToken)
            #if UNITY_IPHONE
            NotificationServices.RegisterForNotifications(
                NotificationType.Alert | 
                NotificationType.Badge | 
                NotificationType.Sound);
            #endif
        }
    }
```

UPDATE 15/06/2015 : Parse Unity SDK 1.5.1 (il2cpp scripting backend)

We re still having the same error when trying to register for parse PNs :

> ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to call method
>   'System.Reflection.MonoProperty::StaticGetterAdapterFrame' for which
>   no ahead of time (AOT) code was generated.
>   System.Reflection.MonoProperty+GetterAdapter.Invoke (System.Object
>   _this) System.Reflection.MonoProperty+GetterAdapter.Invoke (System.Object _this) CurvedText.OnRectTransformDimensionsChange ()
>   System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj,
>   System.Object[] index)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.BsonString.set_IncludeLength (Boolean value)
>   Parse.ParseInstallation.get_Badge ()
>   Parse.ParseInstallation.SetPlatformAutomaticValue ()
>   Parse.ParseInstallation.SetAutomaticValues ()
>   Parse.ParseInstallation.SaveAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.Task
>   toAwait, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   Parse.PlatformHooks+<>c__DisplayClass42.b__36 (System.Object _)
>   Parse.ParseObject+<>c__DisplayClass18.b__17
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task toAwait)
>   FlurryAnalyticsIOS.SetSessionTimeout (Int32 seconds)
>   Parse.ParseObject.SetProperty[ParseACL] (Parse.ParseACL value,
>   System.String propertyName) Parse.Internal.TaskQueue.Enqueue[Task]
>   (System.Func`2 taskStart, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   Parse.ParseObject.SaveAsync (CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   Parse.ParseObject.SaveAsync () Parse.ParseInitializeBehaviour.b__0
>   (System.Byte[] deviceToken) FlurryAnalyticsIOS.SetSessionTimeout
>   (Int32 seconds) Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.BsonString.set_IncludeLength
>   (Boolean value) Parse.PlatformHooks+<>c__DisplayClass24.b__22 ()
>   System.Action.Invoke ()
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.BsonString.set_IncludeLength (Boolean value)
>   Parse.PlatformHooks+d__44.MoveNext ()
>   System.Array+InternalEnumerator`1[System.UInt64].get_Current ()
>   UnityEngine.Debug:LogException(Exception) Parse.d__44:MoveNext()
>   System.InternalEnumerator`1:get_Current()

Comment: iOS is AOT. Reflection isn't available for AOT I thought?

Comment: yes iOS is AOT, but if there was any reflection there would have been an error at build either at unity export or at xCode building iap

Comment: A lot of information is available on the web when searching for 'mono getvalue ios'. It would appear that .GetValue() doesn't play nice, which appears to be the root of your error. Possibly due to use of Generics?

Comment: thank you for your comment Atra Viator, but us I said in my question, its more related to a confilict somewhere than the use of any mono feature not AOT compatible, because the sdk I added works alone and my project runs perfectly alone too.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use reflection with AOT builds (both using the Mono scripting backend and the IL2CPP scripting backend). The restriction is really on using anything in the `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace.

Some parts of the mscorlib.dll assembly that ship with the Unity version of Mono are not friendly to AOT code paths, and `System.Reflection.MonoProperty::StaticGetterAdapterFrame` is one of them. This code won't work with an AOT build, but unfortunately it is not something that Unity can determine at compile time, so the error will only happen at runtime.

This is probably an issue to bring up on the Parse SDK forums. It may be that the SDK can be used differently to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Josh. I just want to bring somthing up, if there was a problem with parse SDK dealing with any non AOT compatible reflection, dont you think it would have showed up when we ran it in an empty unity project ?

Comment: Maybe not actually, as this error can only be detected at runtime. So if an empty project did not take this code path, then the problem might not occur.

Comment: fair enough ! I wrote to parse support (Facebook support) and they are asking me to send them a project that reproduces this error, the problem is not being able to know whats going on make it almost impossible to reproduce it in a sample project (we cant send them our entire game project), all what we have left for now is just work on this sample project to try to reproduce the exception ... its going to be hard.
thank you again for your answers. I ll let you know about the evolution of the situation.